# How to read Text values of node XSLT

Tags: xslt

How can read the value of node/element , which ignores few child tags.
I have List of tags which requires to be Ignored,

Example :

a)
    OUTPUT :Title Txt a

```
<Title>
     <Comment>Comment code</Comment>Title Txt a
 </Title>
```

b)
     OUTPUT :Title Txt b

```
 <Title>
     <Ignore1>Comment code</Ignore1>Title Txt b
 </Title>
```

c)
    OUTPUT :Comment code Title Txt c

```
 <Title>
     <includethis>Comment code</includethis>Title Txt c
 </Title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply match for the `Title` element:

```
<xsl:template match="Title">
```

and output its text content:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Then, process the child nodes in turn:

```
<xsl:template match="*[parent::Title and starts-with(.,'Ignore')]"/>

<xsl:template match="includethis">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Above, the first template matches elements whose name starts with "Ignore". This is because I assume there could me other elements named `Ignore2`, `Ignore3` and so on.

Finally,  the `includethis` elements are matched and their text content is output, same as for the `Title` elements.

Now, to sum up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Title">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[parent::Title and starts-with(.,'Ignore')]"/>

<xsl:template match="includethis">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Help. But i missed to mention the important condition which started the problem,

I need to check the 'Title' for not empty before starting any processing.

example below tag is considered empty, when the child tag is from one from the Ignored List.

```
<Title>
 <Comment>Comment code</Comment>
</Title>
```

Sample Code :

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="Title and normalize-space(Title) != ''">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Title" mode="xyz"/>                    
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-templates name="getalternative_label" mode="xyz"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```